# Pageblocktable colmunswidth does not work

Tags: visualforce

The pageblocktable width does not work, please help!

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="REL_VS_Submission__c" extensions="RELVSRenewalController" sidebar="false">


 <apex:sectionheader title="VSA Renewal Submission" subtitle="Step 2 of 10"/>
    <apex:messages />


 <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock title="Contact Information">
            <!-- This facet tag defines the "Next" button that appears
            in the footer of the pageBlock. It calls the step2()
            controller method, which returns a pageReference to
            the next step of the wizard. -->
            <!--<apex:facet name="footer">
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!step3}" value="Save and Continue"
                                    styleclass="btn" />
            </apex:facet>-->
            <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowContactNumber" />
            <!-- Here we will use an extra variable to define a row number -->
            <apex:outputpanel id="panelWithVar">
                <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="rowContactNumber" />
            </apex:outputpanel>


            <apex:pageblocksection title="Contact Information" >
                <apex:pageblocktable value="{!anewContact}" var="item" id="newContactitems" 
 columnsWidth="5%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%,10%">>
                    <!-- A button to remove individual entry. s
                    We must to pass the line number to define a list entry number to remove -->
                    <apex:column width="5%" headervalue="Delete">
                        <apex:commandbutton immediate="true" action="{!removeContactObject}" value=" X " rerender="newContactitems,panelWithVar">
                            <apex:param name="p2" value="{!rowContactNumber}" assignto="{!numberOfContactRowToRemove}" />
                        </apex:commandbutton>
                    </apex:column>


                    <!-- Moreover here we incrementing the row number variable->
                    <!--<apex:column headerValue="RowCount">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!rowContactNumber}"/>
                    </apex:column>-->

                   <apex:column headervalue="Role">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!item.REL_VS_Contact_Role__c}" html-disabled="true"/>
                        <apex:variable var="rowContactNumber" value="{!rowContactNumber + 1}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Firstname">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!item.Firstname}" required="true" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Lastname">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!item.Lastname}" required="true" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Phone">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!item.Phone}" required="true" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Fax">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!item.Fax}" required="true" />
                    </apex:column>                  
                    <apex:column headervalue="Personal Email">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!item.Email}" required="true" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headervalue="General Email">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!item.REL_VS_Generic_Email__c}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Title">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!item.Title}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:column>
                     <apex:column headervalue="Mailing Street">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!item.MailingStreet}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Mailing City">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!item.MailingCity}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Mailing State">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!item.MailingState}" required="true" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headervalue="Mailing Zip">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!item.MailingPostalCode}" required="true" />
                    </apex:column>
                 </apex:pageblocktable>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
            <!-- A main button to add a new item -->
            <apex:commandbutton value="Add Contact" action="{!addContactObject}" rerender="newContactitems,panelWithVar" immediate="true" />

        </apex:pageblock>
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageblocksection columns="4">
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!step3}" value="Save and Continue"
                                    styleclass="btn" />
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!reset}" value="Reset Page"
                                    styleclass="btn" immediate="true" />
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!exit}" value="Exit"
                                    styleclass="btn" immediate="true" />
                <apex:commandbutton action="{!Back}" value="Back"
                                    styleclass="btn" immediate="true" />
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on a [quick Google](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000970EIAQ), removing the `apex:pageblocksection` so making the table an immediate child of the `apex:pageblock` should result in the widths being honoured.

(Looks like as you have the same title in both you don't really need both. If you did then you are out of luck.)

**PS**

Just did a quick test and the column sizing **now works with or without** the `apex:pageblocksection`. Here is the page that works:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="contacts">

    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! contacts }" var="c" columnsWidth="80%, 10%, 10%">
            <apex:column value="{! c.FirstName }"/>
            <apex:column value="{! c.LastName }"/>
            <apex:column value="{! c.Birthdate }"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! contacts }" var="c" columnsWidth="80%, 10%, 10%">
                <apex:column value="{! c.FirstName }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! c.LastName }"/>
                <apex:column value="{! c.Birthdate }"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

producing this output:

[image: Sample Output]

Suggest you simplify your page back to this and then add back in stuff until you discover what is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Keith. Even If i remove the pageblocksection, the columns width is not controlled. I tried removing it but no luck.

Comment: I tried but still did not work for me.

Comment: @mvr Start with say just 3 columns and significantly different percentages. You may be running into how browsers compromise on widths when there is too much data to show.

Comment: I tried this and no matter how I simplied/altered my page/pageBlock/pageBlockSection it would just not obey my columWidths attribute values. *IF* this does work it's super picky I guess. I ended up having to force/override it using CSS with td:nth-child() type stylesheet rules - very annoying. Hoping one day to find what I am doing wrong.